# How do I find a journal's type (e.g. SCI, EI)?

Tags: journals

I'm filling out a form with information about my publications, and one of the fields is "Type of Journal." I'm not sure what this means, except that SCI and EI are possible values. I'm guessing the former refers to [Science Citation Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Citation_Index), but I can't find what EI is. It seems this is something they are expecting me to know so I can only assume it is common knowledge among academics.

What are the possible types for a journal (if a comprehensive list exists), and most importantly, for any given journal how do I find its type?

Comment: Why don't you ask from where you take the form? Because even if you find a complete list, nobody can specifically tell what do they expect and mean by "type of journal" except themselves.

Comment: Consider editing the title to include abbreviations in question.

Comment: EI stands for [Engineering Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compendex).

Comment: @Parsa I already asked, but I didn't get much useful information - all they told me was basically "SCI or EI, etc." I posted the question here because I thought there was a standard classification and that having this information here would be useful to others.

Answer (score 4):

I have set up a webpage ([**click here**](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/links.php)) which provides links to the list of journals that are SCI, SCIE, ISI and EI and also let you check the impact factor of a journal. You can follow the links on that page to find out if a given journal is EI, SCI, SCIE, etc. Hope that it helps!

Comment: I get internal server errors when trying to access the lists.

Comment: Hi @davidZ . Thanks for the comment. I have fixed the issue.  You can now click on the link.  Then click "view journal lists"  then click "Format for print A-Z" to get a convenient list of the journals. Let me know if there is some other problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering if those refer to ISI (and/or  other organizations) list of journals

- SCI: Science Citation Index (Thomson Reuters or ISI)
- SCIE: Science Citation Index Extended (Thomson Reuters or ISI)
- SSCI: Social Science Citation Index (Thomson Reuters or ISI)
- A&HCI: Arts & Humanities Citation Index (Thomson Reuters or ISI)
- EI: Engineering Index or Compendex (Elsevier)

You can find the list of those journals in their perspective sites or just by searching their search engines.

Comment: I suppose it's something like that, but then the rest of my question (which I understand that you may not know about) would be: how would I find which type a given journal is? Just go to each of these sites and search for the journal to see which one it comes up in? What if there's more than one?